# Ultrawide monitor support (2560x1080) on AndroidTV 13.0?

Tags: android-tv, screen-resolution

I have a chinese AndroidTV box, with Android 13. Resolution in the settings are standard - 1920x1080, 4K etc. No ultrawide.
I have tried changing through `adb wm size`, but it chooses the closest supported resolution - 4K.

Is there a method to achieve that with some custom rom I don't know about? Or some other method?

Thanks

Comment: AndroidTV seems to expect a fixed ratio of 16:9: https://developer.android.com/design/ui/tv/guides/styles/layouts#highlights

Comment: And I'd be willing to stretch the activities, if it would give me full resolution and unstretched video.